# Parametrizing the element description in setElementsByID calls

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a large number of polyline elements in an SVG file identified in the controlling ECMAScript as:

```
polyline_element_1_1
polyline_element_1_2
polyline_element_1_3
```

etc

As there will be many tens of these elements, I wish to set their opacity individually according to a global variable n corresponding to the second digit in the element description, to as to avoid having multiple lines in the function like this:

```
if (n == 1) {polyline_element_1_1.setAttribute('opacity',1);}
if (n == 2) {polyline_element_1_2.setAttribute('opacity',1);}
if (n == 3) {polyline_element_1_3.setAttribute('opacity',1);}
```

etc

I have tried:

`polyline_element_1_($n).setAttribute('opacity',1);`

but it didn't work - and a long session of online searching hasn't uncovered the solution.

Assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps better like this: `const polyline_elements = document.querySelectorAll("#mySVG polyline['someAttribute']"); polyline_elements.forEach(pl => pl.setAttribute('opacity',1));`

Comment: I believe this sets all the polyline opacities to 1. I need to be able set them individually.

Comment: Since you did not bother to post actual code, I could only guess

Comment: You write "n corresponding to the second digit in the element description". What description is that? Can you share the code for one of the polyllines?